# Get posts inside Get terms problem

Tags: get-posts, terms, php, tags

i have a get_terms which loads correctly.
inside of it i have used get_posts. then using get posts i am
trying to get each post tags (and count <= not currently inside this script)

```
<?php
    $categories = get_terms( 'blogs_cat', array(
        'type'                     => 'blogs',
        'orderby'                  => 'name',
        'order'                    => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'               => 0,
        'exclude'                  => '1',
        'number'                   => '1000',
        'pad_counts'               => true 
        )
    ); 

    echo '<div class="clientList">';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $colorClass = '';

        // COUNT NUMBER OF TAGS AKA: PUBLISHED / NOT PUBLISHED ARTICLES
        $termID = $category->term_id;
        $taxonomyNAME = $category->taxonomy;
        $termSLUG = $category->slug;

        $items = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'   => 'blogs',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'taxonomy'    => $taxonomyNAME,
            'term'        => $termSLUG
            ) );
        $totalPostsCount =  count( $items );

        // WHEN PRINT_R EACH ITEM RETURNS UNIQE ID
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $posttags = get_the_tags($item->term_id);
            if ($posttags) {
              foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                // HERE I GET SAME TAG NAME FOR ALL TAGS ACROSS POSTS (IN THIS CASE ITEMS)
                echo $tag->name; 
              } 
            }
        }


        //print_r($category);
        echo '<li class="'.$listClass.'"><div class="clientContainer"><a href="' . get_term_link($category->slug, 'blogs_cat') . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "All Articles By: %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a><div class="articleCount '.$colorClass.'"> ('.$totalPostsCount.' / p'.$publishedArticle.') </div></div></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

.

The Issuse is "echo $tag->name;" returns always the same tag.. 
can anyone help me to spot the problem / offer a better way
i might have gotten mixed with this script.

Thanks

**EDIT 1 - RESPONSE TO: @tollmanz**

when i *"print_r($item);"* inside the foreach i get this
(similer to each post that exist with its own details):

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [ID] => 875 
    [post_author] => 1 
    [post_date] => 2012-06-25 14:34:53 
    [post_date_gmt] => 2012-06-25 11:34:53 
    [post_content] => Content Content Content
    [post_title] => itle Example
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish 
    [comment_status] => open 
    [ping_status] => open 
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => post-name 
    [menu_order] => 0 
    [post_type] => blogs 
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0 
    [filter] => raw 
)
```

.

Also... When i *"echo $item->ID;"*  i get the correct post id.
.
BUt when i try to *"print_r($posttags);"*
after this line: *"$posttags = get_the_tags($item->ID);"*
.
**i get nothing...   any ideas why?**

Answer (score 1):

When you do the following in your code `$posttags = get_the_tags($item->term_id);`, `$item` is referring to a post object, not a term object. Therefore, `term_id` is an invalid property. This should be throwing a PHP notice.

While not certain, I think what you are intending to do is:

```
$posttags = get_the_tags($item->ID);
```

since `get_the_tags` takes a post ID, not a term ID.

Comment: hey @tollmanz - thanks for stoping by ;) - i edited and added some information to my answer after trying to relate to the ID of the post.